# Bootstrap navbar link and JavaScript - Cannot read property 'slice' of 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-events

I am trying to do something simple with bootstrap and JS. I have a BS navbar with two links - `add` and `edit`. When I click on one of these two links I simply want to change the content that is displayed in the respective `divs` for `add` and `edit`, but this does not work. I get a `cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` error.

Here is the HTML and BS:

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="menu-btn active"><a href="#add">Add Product<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li class="menu-btn"><a href="#edit">Edit Product</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  <div class="menu-content add">add</div>
  <div class="menu-content edit">edit</div>
```

And here is the JS :

```
var $content = $('.menu-content');

    function showContent(type) {
      $content.hide().filter('.' + type).show();
    }

    $('.menu').on('click', '.menu-btn', function(e) {
      var a = e;
      console.log(a);
      showContent(e.currentTarget.hash.slice(1));
      e.preventDefault();
    });
   showContent('add');
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error means what it says.. `e.currentTarget.hash` is not defined. You want the check if it's defined before using the slice() method.

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed it with some minor changes :

Bootstrap :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a class="menu-btn" href="#add">Add Product<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="menu-btn" href="#edit">Edit Product</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  <div id="add" class="menu-content">add</div>
  <div id="edit" class="menu-content">edit</div>
```

JS :

```
  var $content = $('.menu-content');

function showContent(selector) {
  $content.hide();
  $(selector).show();
}

$('.menu').on('click', '.menu-btn', function(e) {
  showContent(e.currentTarget.hash);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// show '#about' content only on page load (if you want)
showContent('#add');
```

Hope this can help someone in future : )